# API segura depende inteiramente do desenvolvedor ou plataforma?

Tags: api, segurança, mobile

Quais os desafios que o programador encontra para tornar sua API totalmente segura? Quando falo de segurança me refiro diretamente se a aplicação expõe as informações do cliente ou mesmo deixa sua aplicação fácil de ser penetrada.

Depende inteiramente do programador ou da plataforma? (Android ou Iphone).

Comment: Faro. Você poderia definir o que é "seguro"? Note que nada é *totalmente seguro*, entretanto, se especificar alguns requisitos mínimos pode-se chegar a um conceito *razoável*.

Comment: Quando falo de segurança me refiro diretamente se a aplicação expõe as informações do cliente ou mesmo deixa sua aplicação fácil de ser penetrada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem, depende de ambos.

A API muitas vezes é o diferencial de cada linguagem: eu, por exemplo, acho o C++ superior ao Java como linguagem. Mas a API do Java é extensivamente mais prática que a Biblioteca Padrão do C++. Por isso, se eu tivesse que escolher entre as duas para um projeto comercial, provavelmente escolheria Java.

Semelhantemente acontece com as APIs de sistemas: Depende de quem desenvolveu a API e de quem a consome. Mas depende **principalmente** de quem a desenvolveu.

Se a API foi desenvolvida bem seguramente mas o cliente a usa de mal modo, esse problema é exclusivo do cliente. O cliente poderá expor mal seus dados, mas isso não afetará de modo algum o servidor.

Já se a API foi desenvolvida com brechas de segurança, até o mais cuidadoso dos clientes pode ter sua segurança afetada. Ele não pode fazer mudanças de segurança no servidor; ele depende daquela API ruim. O máximo que ele pode fazer é ser cuidadoso em sua aplicação e torcer pra que ninguém tente usar o servidor mal-desenvolvido para prejudicá-lo.

**Resumindo**: Depende de ambos, mas principalmente de quem desenvolveu a API -- e não de quem a consome.

Answer (score 1):

Totalmente segura não existe. A primeira pergunta que você deve fazer é: Seguro a que tipo de ataques?

Quando eu ouço a palavra API, eu entendo que a pessoa esteja fazendo alguma biblioteca para fazer algo. Para melhorar a API do Android, a gente tem que codar para a API do Android. Agora, se quer melhorar um determinado software, depende do que você quer fazer. Meu sistema vai fazer transações financeiras. Beleza, aí você tem que tomar várias medidas. Usar um teclado próprio para não haver keylogger. Verificar se o celular está rooteado. Fazer requisições https. Para se ter segurança, é preciso pensar como atacante

Answer (score 0):

A segurança de informações em sistemas depende quase inteiramente do desenvolvedor. Não importa quantas configurações e quantos padrões de segurança uma aplicação use, você não terá segurança se:

1. Concatenar valores em queries.
2. Listar dados confidenciais numa tela ou relatório por algum equívoco.
3. Permitir ao usuário administrador gerenciar o Controle de Acesso e este dar permissão desnecessária para os usuários
4. Não proteger a rede adequadamente
5. Não proteger o servidor de banco de dados adequadamente

Enfim, independentemente da API, se a implementação dá acesso legítimo a dados que alguém não poderia acessar, de nada adianta colocar várias camadas de segurança.

O que poderia diferenciar uma API da outra pode ser a facilidade e flexibilidade para declarar as permissões necessárias.

Obviamente, não considerei possíveis *bugs* nas APIs, por isso a sugestão é usar as que já estão consolidadas e são bastante usadas, de forma que possíveis brechas são identificadas pela comunidade de desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 0):

Os aspectos de segurança residem sobre o seu servidor e não sobre o Android ou iOS, ambas as plataformas são robustas e estão maduras em termos de segurança.

Sugiro fazer em cima de um bom firewall e servidor de aplicação consolidade pois eles já passaram por um crivo de segurança grande no passado, se você optar por fazer um ambiente servidor em nodejs vai estar sujeito à muitos problemas de vunerabilidades.